compiler finds both std::to_address and cuda::std::to_address
I'm trying to build the Nvidia's Minkowski Engine, so I did the following:
git clone 
https://github.com/NVIDIA/MinkowskiEngine.git
cd MinkowskiEngine
python setup.py install

However, I get this error:
error: more than one instance of overloaded function "std::__to_address" matches the argument list:
            function template "_Tp *cuda::std::__4::__to_address(_Tp *) noexcept" (declared at line 277 of /usr/local/cuda-12.4/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/__memory/pointer_traits.h)
            function template "_Tp *std::__to_address(_Tp *) noexcept" (declared at line 156 of /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ptr_traits.h)

So there seems to be two definitions of the function std::to_address, the cuda::std::to_address and the std::to_address. However, the to_address function itself doesn't appear anywhere in the code.
How can I solve this?
Configuration:
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Python version: 3.8.10
Pytorch version: 2.2.1
CUDA version: 12.4
NVIDIA Driver version: 525.147.05
Minkowski Engine version 0.5.4


I guess you have already posted an issue on the repo which is good. libcudacxx is under active development, so probably this issue only appeared with a recent version of the Toolkit and the packaged version of CCCL/libcudacxx. So as a quick fix you could downgrade the version of the CUDA Toolkit that you are using.

I would guess that to_address enters the project through the header-only Thrust library that is also part of CCCL and which is used in Minkowski Engine.

There is also already a PR for fixing the built with CUDA 12.2. It doesn't look like it would fix your issue but who knows. You could downgrade to CUDA 12.2 and use that PR's fork instead of the release or downgrade the Toolkit even further.
